# Allow Read and write for all child except one

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rules

I am using firebase for my project

now I wan to customize my Rule

the Default rules is  :

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

which Allow to read and write all data for Authorized users

now I want to Allow read and write all data for Authorized users

and I want to add this too

```
{
  "rules": {
      "visits": {
      "$visit_id": {
        "mister_id": {
          ".write": "data.val() == ''"
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Now how Can I add this two Rules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need something like that :

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null",
        "visits": {
            "$visit_id": {
                "mister_id": {
                    ".validate": "(data.val() == null) || (data.isString() && (data.val().length == 0))"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can find all what you need with the [Firebase Datase Rules documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).

Comment: NO it`s Not allow to write in any child 
and Thanx For Attention

Comment: Ok I just want to allow read and write for all node (Authrize)
But dont allow to update "visit/visit_id/mister_id"
if it`s value != ' ' ;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149848/discussion-between-pipiks-and-elsunhoty).

Comment: it`s works for 1st time when I try on exist data  but when I add new data it didn`t work

Answer (score 2):

Haven't try yet but it may be another solution:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null",
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['visit_id', 'mister_id'])"
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I just want to allow read and write for all node (Authrize) But dont allow to update  "visit/visit_id/mister_id" if exist value   value != ' ' ;

Comment: could You Help me Alittle Please /

Comment: did u mean empty string? or null? if u mean empty, u can add (&& newData.val().length > 0) condition to validation part given above. for supported string operations see https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/08/new-feature-improved-string-validation.html

Comment: Ok I will try it , Thanx